# .NET C# Read Excel file DateTime Column read 1 second less, why?

Tags: .net, excel, datetime

I have a an excel file and one of it's columns has DateTime value:

```
01.03.2012 10:00
02.03.2012 10:00
03.03.2012 10:00
04.03.2012 10:00
```

And I'm reading with this code:

```
OleDbDataAdapter command = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "$]", Conn);
command.Fill(Result);
```

Interestingly, the data from the excel file comes exactly like this (1st column is correct but other 1 second less)

```
01.03.2012 10:00:00
02.03.2012 09:59:59
03.03.2012 09:59:59
04.03.2012 09:59:59
```

And the rest values are going 09:59:59... Only the first value comes to datatable correctly.

Why am I having this problem and any idea how to get them exactly the way it is on the Excel file?

I'd totally appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really 10:00 in your Excel sheet because Excel does not hold times in that format:

- One second is held as 1/(24*60*60) = 0.00001157407
- 10:00:00 is held as 0.41666666667
- 9:59:59 is held as 0.41665509259

Copy your times to other cells and format them as numbers with seven or eight decimal places.  My guess is that the values converted to 9:59:59 are less than 0.41666666667 and are being truncated rather than rounded.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you actually have `09:59:59` in the Excel spreadsheet, and it is the display format that 'rounds' the time to `10:00`. Check what cell formatting is applied.

Comment: Yes, this is the only possible solution I see. Never had this problem

Comment: It really is 10:00 in my Excel sheet as I copied into my question above not 09:59:59. In fact in the same Excel file but in a different Sheet, there is 19:00 and it is read as 19:00:00 on C#. And I checked it again for 10:00 it really is 10:00:00..